# Grey out a dropdown, dynamically activate when option is selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have three dropdowns, which are all loaded in the same function.  How do I grey out dropdown 2 & 3?  I want them to activate if a certain choice is made on dropdown 1.

Comment: are you using Ajax Control Toolkit?

Comment: Could you post some sample code of what your dropdown code looks like now?  It will make it a lot easier to provide a solution that is clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the AJAX ControlKit you can use cascading dropdowns:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

If not you can add an event handler for each drop box OnSelectedIndexChanged, then perfom your logic on postback. (set textbox 1 & 2 do .Enable = false onLoad)

```
if(Textbox1.Text == "hello world"){
Textbox2.enabled = true;
}
```

Or you can use javascript to do it clientside like this: so disable the postback for the dropdown, use the OnClient javascript hooks and implement enable/disable in javascript.

```
function checkDrop(DropDown)
{
  ...check logic disable Dropdown etc
  document.getElementById(DropDown).disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question.
Make `AutoPostBack="True"` on your first `dropdownlist`.
Then in the

```
protected void DropdownlistSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
       //get the selected item
       var item = Dropdownlist.SelectedItem.ToString();
       // depending on the item you can grey the other dropdowns
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.Net:

```
   myDD.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(235, 235, 228)
```